# Is it correct/natural to say "don't mingle with a crowd. It's dangerous."?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

When I was young, my dad often said "avoid crowds. You might get killed."

When there is an accident or a fight, a lot of people gather to watch it. Say, if that was an accident, the vehicle might explore. If that was a fight, the fighters might have grenades or guns and you might get killed by stray bullets.

Say, you want to be a part of a crowd so that you can watch things just like the others people in the crowd.

Can I say "**I mingled with the crowd**" in thus situation?

Comment: Yes it's fine. Google Books has plenty hits. What concerns do you have? "a" vs "the"? Tense? The verb "mingle"? Something else.

Comment: Title question doesn't match body.

Comment: "Mingle" implies some sort of social interaction with the people in the crowd. In the context you're describing "don't join a crowd" or "I joined the crowed" would suit better.